# javascript prevents file_get_contents

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to scrap the data from the website using `file_get_contents` but instead of the webpage source I'm getting following code:

```
<body onload="challenge();">
<script>eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return c.toString(a)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('1 6(){2.3=\'4=5; 0-7=8; 9=/\';a.b.c()}',13,13,'tax|function|document|cookie|ddosdefend|1d4607e3ac67b865e6c7263260c34e888cae7c56|challenge|age|0|path|window|location|reload'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Engine is wordpress. Is there any chance to get real source?

Comment: Did you try downloading that webpage with e.g. `wget` and inspecting the file? The file_get_contents function seems to do its job proberly, you just have to run the embedded javascript code of that webpage to get any meaningful output.

Comment: Seems like the output is from a DDOS protection (e.g. something like CouldFlare) which might present your scraper with a captcha before serving the desired content.

Comment: well when i try to enter website with browser it load normally without captcha and redirection

Comment: Browsers execute Javascript, `file_get_contents()` doesn't. It just returns the HTML code with the Javascript embedded in it.

Comment: @GeorgeSamarguliani Usually, a DDOS protection service is a proxy between the original webserver and your scraper. It inspects your request behavior / user agent etc. and based on that serves you either the original webserver's content or presents you a challenge (e.g. captcha, or simply requires you to evaluate javascript etc.).

Comment: is there any chance of bypassing it ?

Comment: @GeorgeSamarguliani If you can get the IP address of the original webserver, you might be able to directly access it. The DNS resolution for the webserver's name will direct you to the proxy, so you have to look elsewhere. Alternatively, use one of the many web scraping libraries that emulate real browser behavior.

Comment: @le_m can you advise web scraping libraries that emulate real browser behavior?

Comment: @GeorgeSamarguliani Sorry, I have no personal experience with such libraries.

Answer (score -1):

`file_get_contents` seems to work fine. However, it seems you are not served the desired content but some JavaScript code which needs to be evaluated before redirecting to the content.

This might be because the website you want to scrape uses a DDOS protection (e.g. something like CouldFlare) which detects your simple scraping attempt.

Usually, a DDOS protection service is a proxy between the original webserver and your scraper. It inspects your request behavior, user agent etc. and based on that serves you either the original webserver's content or presents you a challenge (e.g. captcha, or simply requires you to evaluate javascript etc.).

If you can get the IP address of the original webserver, you might be able to directly access it. The DNS resolution for the webserver's name will direct you to the proxy, so you have to look elsewhere. Alternatively, use a web scraping library that emulates real browser behavior in PHP.

Comment: i checked dns entries and it is cloudflare please advise how to bypass it ?

Comment: @GeorgeSamarguliani If you can bypass Cloudflare, then it is by a mistake of the server administrator (because it renders the Cloudflare protection useless). Sometimes, the original server's IP address can be found in an email send directly from the webserver. Or an information disclosure vulnerability on the server software discloses the IP. However, chances are that you can't find the original IP.

Comment: well is there any other methods of getting part of source code from the webpage by avoiding cloudflare protetcion ?

Comment: well, no, you have to trick CloudFlare into believing you are a human visitor and not a scraper. Which is what many web scraping libraries for PHP do. Just google it and give it a try.

Comment: i have ip adress which is directing to Centmin Mod Nginx Test Page what do i do next ?

Comment: @GeorgeSamarguliani You need to send a HTTP GET request to the IP including the 'Host: example.com' header - replacing example.com with your specific website.